# Execute JAR of dependent artifact in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, executable-jar, exec-maven-plugin

I'm working on a multi-module Maven project which looks like this:

```
Parent-project (pom)
+- Module1 (executable-jar)
+- Module2 (executable-jar)
+- Module3 (jar)
+- ...
+- Distribution (pom)
```

The Distribution module lists dependencies on Module1, Module2, and Module3. I want the Distribution module to test the project and package it up. I'm using this module for testing since the distribution already contains all the necessary configuration files. If I were to start the tests manually from the command line it would look something like this:

```
$ # Pre-integration-test:
$ java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:module3.jar -jar module1.jar
$ java -Djava.rmi.codebase=file:module3.jar -jar module2.jar
```

I've looked at the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) for binding these calls to the pre-integration-test phase, but the plugin only includes the JARs on the classpath instead of the directory holding the JAR itself. I think I would benefit most from a plugin which can easliy execute jars produced by a project's dependencies. That way, I can do something like this in the Distribution POM:

```
...
<plugin>
  <artifactId>some-magic-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions><execution>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals><goal>exec-dependency</goal></goals>
    <configuration>
      <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
      <vmArguments>...</vmArguments>
      <arguments>...</arguments>
    </configuration>
  </execution></executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there already a plugin for this? Ideally, it would be able to:

1. Execute a JAR artifact given its Maven-coordinates
2. Put directories containing the artifacts' JARs on the path (so I can include the JARs with command line arguments)

I've laso looked at dependency:copy goal to try and copy all JARs to a common path first, but it seems unnecessary since the jars are already built as part of the project. (I'm also not sure which directory would make the best copy-destination).